# Server sends success even if didn't find anything

Tags: node.js, database, express, mongoose

I send data from my input fields to my api:

```
  $.ajax({
       url: '/api/login',
       type: 'GET',  
       dataType: 'json',  
       ContentType: 'application/json',
       data: {formData},
       success: (data) => {
         console.log('SUCCESS')
         console.log(data)
         this.setState({
           isInProcess: false
         })
       },  
       error: (jqXHR) => {
         console.log(jqXHR)
         console.log('ERROR')
         this.setState({isInProcess: false})
       } 
    })
```

on my server-side I have a function to see if I have required user in db:

```
async function findUser(data) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({email: data.email,
                                     password: data.password})
    console.log('User was found')
    return { user }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error', err)
    throw err
  }
}
```

which will be executed here:

```
app.get('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.query
  try {
    const foundUserData = await findUser(data.formData)
    return res.json(foundUserData)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json(err)
  }
})
```

It works fine, but if a user wasn't found in db i sends success anyway.[image] Why?

Comment: because there was no error, catch is only called when an error is thrown

Comment: my fucntion findUser throws an error

Comment: ‘User.findOne’ returns an empty document if no equal is found, so while your ’findUser’ can throw an error it wont because it never triggers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await findUser(data.formData)` won't throw error, return either `null` or user object. You may check something following

```
app.get('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.query
  try {
    const foundUserData = await findUser(data.formData)
    if(foundUserData && foundUserData.user) {
      return res.json(foundUserData)
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({message: 'User not found'});
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It sends success because none of your queries error'ed, just because it didn't find anything does not mean that the query failed because it obviously succeeded in finding out if what ever you're looking for exists or not.

To send an error in case of not found you need to check if response is empty in which case you want to send error

Answer (score 0):

When no user is find you get a `null` value. You may try to put more logic on your success parameter with that for example:

```
success: function (data) {
    if(!!data && data != null) {
        alert('Success');
    } else {
        alert('No data');
    }
}
```